# Receiving a call downgrades to 3G/H permanently?

Tags: tethering, 4g, nexus-5x

#### Some background

I'm using my Nexus 5X running Android 7.1.2 as a wifi access point for my computers. I'm subscribed to an unlimited 4G plan, no upper limits. I got the phone last Fall, which is also when I switched from a wired ADSL connection, and this has been a consistent problem.

#### The problem itself

Whenever I receive a phone call, the mobile signal downgrades from 4G to H and speeds drop significantly (as one would expect). This isn't a problem in itself; 4G is exclusively for mobile data. But after the call has ended, **the phone can't reacquire 4G until I restart it** or turn off tethering *for a long time*. Turning mobile data on/off to reacquire the connection does not work.

#### What now

Obviously having to reboot the phone every time I receive a phone call is bad, so what can I do about it? I don't use my phone or Android a lot so I might just be missing something obvious here.

#### Not working

- Toggling airplane mode does not restore 4G
- Toggling mobile data does not restore 4G

Comment: It's not permanent... it's until the connections are closed. Android isn't going to switch it's HSPA/LTE connection while network connections are active to prevent loss of information, this is normal behavior. When you toggle off hotspot all your open connections are closed and the device sees the network as idle and switches back to LTE without interruption. At least that is how all of our devices work.

Comment: ...but it happily switches *down to* HSPA from LTE while connections are active..?